# My php code is very slow and timeout error appears

Tags: php

I have a soccer fantasy league script and every week I add a points to the users, using this code:

```
$sql_user="select * from ".$prev."user ";

$re_user=mysql_query($sql_user);
while($d_user=mysql_fetch_array($re_user))
{
$userID=$d_user['id'];

$sql_addpointgroup="select * from ".$prev."addpoint group by weekno order by weekno";
$re_addpointgroup=mysql_query($sql_addpointgroup);
while($d_addpointgroup=mysql_fetch_array($re_addpointgroup))
{       
  $points=0;
  $sql_addpoint="select * from ".$prev."addpoint where weekno='".$d_addpointgroup['weekno']."'";
  $re_addpoint=mysql_query($sql_addpoint);
  while($d_addpoint=mysql_fetch_array($re_addpoint))
  {
    $points=$d_addpoint['points'];
    $sql_weekstatistic="select * from ".$prev."weekstatistic where weekno='".$d_addpointgroup['weekno']."' and userID='$userID' and playerID='".$d_addpoint['playerID']."'";
    $re_weekstatistic=mysql_query($sql_weekstatistic);
    if(mysql_num_rows($re_weekstatistic)>0)
    {
        $sql_update="update ".$prev."weekstatistic set points='$points' where weekno='".$d_addpointgroup['weekno']."' and userID='$userID' and playerID='".$d_addpoint['playerID']."'";

        mysql_query($sql_update);
    }
  }
}   
}
```

in the beginning this code was working fine, but after the number of registered users reached the 500 users, the updating process now is very slow and some times timeout error msg appears.

Is there any way to rewrite this code, so to do the updating process faster?

many thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm heading out and can't give a full answer, but I'm pretty sure a judicious `JOIN` will allow you to do this in one loop rather than nested loops. If I'm correct, you'd dramatically improve the performance that way.

Comment: Can you give us a sense of what your db structure looks like? As KRyan hinted at, the goal should be remove as many queries as possible from while/foreach loops. Accessing the database is very slow, so you want to do it as few times as possible. Going to the database one time and grabbing a ton of data all at once is waay faster than hitting the database 500 times.

Comment: How can this be slow? `while { while { while { } } }`

Comment: Thank you KRyan,
Actually I'm  a beginner in writing php codes and that code was written by php developer, could you please rewrite the code using Join.

Comment: any suggestions JvdBerg?

Answer (score 0):

The nested loops mean you could easily be running thousands of queries just to get the data you want. Try `join` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM addpoint GROUP BY weekno ORDER BY weekno) AS a JOIN addpoint USING weekno
```

Using that query, you can loop through just one result array.

As for the update, here's a shortcut you can use. However, you can ONLY use this if `weekno` is defined as a unique index on the table.

```
INSERT INTO weekstatistic (weekno,points) VALUES {$vals} ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points=VALUES(points)
```

`{$vals}` should be a comma-separated list of weekno/points values:

```
$tmp = Array();
// build an array like so:
$tmp[] = "('".$weekno."','".$points."')";
// at the end of the loop:
$vals = implode(",",$tmp);
// now run the query.
```

Ideally, you can do everything in just two queries.

Comment: didn't worked my friends, or may be I didn't wrote it in the right way